# IBM.Data.db2.dll 64bit vs 32

Tags: .net, db2, 32bit-64bit

I have application developed in VS2013 with targeted .net Framework 4.5.2 we are using IBM.Data.db2.dll (32 bit) to communincate with DB2 database. Our application is compiled for x64 system and server where we have deployed application is also 64bit OS. The problem is 32-bit IBM dll is consuming los of memory on server and performance of application is very slow. If I use the 64 bit IBM dll, will it resolve the slowness issue ?

Comment: I doubt it, probably something fundamentally wrong with your db design and/or queries.

Comment: Once we replaced the 32bit dll with 64 bit dll performace of the application was superb, we have seen memory leakage and performance related issue with 32 bit dll.

Answer (score 0):

Move to all 64 bit and you will see performance increase.